# Ruby / Sinatra - Route any HTTP request to HTTPS (using Rack::SSL) - !! Invalid request

Tags: ruby, ssl, sinatra

I'm playing with Ruby / Sinatra at present and attempting to get HTTPS working.
I've taken a look at the rack:ssl gem here: https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl

It seems to be working when I run the application (as in redirecting to HTTPS), but nothing is displayed in the browser and the log comes up with the following error:

**!! Invalid request**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

    require 'rack/ssl'
    require 'sinatra'

    use Rack::SSL

    get '/' do
        'Hello World'
    end
```

I'm not sure what to do from here.

Update:

Turned Thin Logging on in the sinatra app and got the following in the log:

```
!! Invalid request
Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/request.rb:82:in `execute'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/request.rb:82:in `parse'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1408:in `run!'
/Users/ashleycox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How are you serving up the app? Did you pass SSL options (path to cert and key) to Thin when executing the app?